# NSURL declaration /allocation showing error

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I Have tried

```
NSString *alertTxt =textfieldName.text;
NSLog(@"Name: %@",alertTxt);
NSURL *urlAddress = [[NSURL alloc ] initWithString: @"%@/login/index.php",alertTxt];
```

error : too many argument to function initstring ..

the user will giv the url address to the alertText field and i hav to embed in to the webkit may i know the process how to make it !!!

Where im making mistake kindly help me out in this

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-initWithString:` can only take a complete string, not a format string. To use `-initWithString:` you need to complete the string first.

```
NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/login/index.php", alertTxt];
NSURL* urlAddress = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
```

BTW, it may be more efficient to use `-stringByAppendingString:`.

```
NSString* urlString = [alertTxt stringByAppendingString:@"/login/index.php"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Kenny 
i have solved the issue by stringWithFormat.